# Configuring HUSKY with SOURCETREE

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, husky

I'm currently trying to set sourcetree with husky from my project. I'm getting the following issue when trying to commit:

```
git -c color.branch=false -c color.diff=false -c color.status=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree commit -q -F /var/folders/76/hhf0w6rx1h9221kn9m6nrh700000gn/T/SourceTreeTemp.sYVLL0 -a 
.husky/pre-commit: line 4: yarn: command not found
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)
husky - command not found in PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core:/Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/Resources/bin:/usr/bin:/Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/gitflow:/Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/git-lfs:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Completed with errors, see above
```